# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2410 in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv

i am trying to capture camera with opencv version 2410 but this exception 
appear although path is right
iam try to open camera and capture video from camera but this exception appear
iam searched in many sites but nothing same words

> > netbeans 8.0.2

how can i solve it ?

```
output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2410 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at videocap.VideoCap.main(VideoCap.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

code here

```
VideoCap.java
package videocap;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;        
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;     

 public class VideoCap {


 public static void main (String args[]){
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

    if(!camera.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    else {
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        while(true){
            if (camera.read(frame)){
                System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
                System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());
                Highgui.imwrite("camera.jpg", frame);
                System.out.println("OK");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    camera.release();
}

}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include native library we need to add following steps in netbeans

```
 ==>Right click on the Project
 ==>Properties
 ==>Click on RUN
 ==>VM Options : -Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is present"
 ==>Ok
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. For some reason it's still trying to look in the default location. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?