# Java: UnsatisfiedLinkError after compiling

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, unsatisfiedlinkerror

When I run the program through Netbeans it runs fine, but after compiling and executing the .jar I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2410 in
 java.library.path`

The line giving the error is: `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);`
When I run this code`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` it gives me `C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\opencv\build\java\x64\` which is where the opencv_java2410.dll is located

I'm trying to use the opencv 2410 library, and have it added to the project. It works perfectly inside Netbeans, but not outside, not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: how do you call `loadLibrary` ? show that part of code

Comment: It could be calling `MS Office` do you have it installed. Some thing native is missing.

Comment: System.loadLibrary(...) is a bit strict. If you can accept to hardcode your path (or get it on some other way) you can try to use System.load("C:\\<path>\\opencv_java2410.dll") instead

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356974/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-opencv-java2410-in